# Converting a PHP array into a Javascript one

Tags: javascript, php

After looking online for an answer, I couldn't find solution to my problem:
I kept getting an array with a length of 1.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo "var PlayerPokemon1 = ".$jsPoke1.";\n";
?>
```

Which returns

```
PlayerPokemon1 = [{"Number":"9","0":"9","Name":"Rock Slide","1":"Blastoise","Type1":"Water","2":"Water","Type2":"","3":"","HP":"362","4":"362","Attack":"295","5":"295"}]
```

This is all just one huge object, and what I want to achieve is something like

> PlayerPokemon1 = ["9", "9", "Rock Slide", "Blastoise", "Water"]

And so on...

I've tried this other method

```
$numArray = count($jsPoke1);
for ($i=0; i<$numArray; i++)
{
    echo "PlayerPokemon1[$i] = ".jsPoke1[$i].";\n";
}
```

But to no avail.

Edit:

```
print_r ($poke1);

gives this:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Number] => 9 [0] => 9 [Name] => Rock Slide [1] => Blastoise [Type1] => Water [2] => Water [Type2] => [3] => [HP] => 362 [4] => 362 [Attack] => 295 [5] => 295 [Defense] => 339 [6] => 339 [Speed] => 280 [7] => 280 [Move1] => Aqua Tail [8] => Aqua Tail [Move2] => Ice Beam [9] => Ice Beam [Move3] => Dark Pulse [10] => Dark Pulse [Move4] => Rock Slide [11] => Rock Slide [12] => Aqua Tail [Type] => Rock [13] => Water [Power] => 75 [14] => 90 [15] => Ice Beam [16] => Ice [17] => 90 [18] => Dark Pulse [19] => Dark [20] => 80 [21] => Rock Slide [22] => Rock [23] => 75 ) )
```

And

```
$jsPoke1 = json_encode($Poke1);
print_r ($jsPoke1);

[{"Number":"9","0":"9","Name":"Rock Slide","1":"Blastoise","Type1":"Water","2":"Water","Type2":"","3":"","HP":"362","4":"362","Attack":"295","5":"295","Defense":"339","6":"339","Speed":"280","7":"280","Move1":"Aqua Tail","8":"Aqua Tail","Move2":"Ice Beam","9":"Ice Beam","Move3":"Dark Pulse","10":"Dark Pulse","Move4":"Rock Slide","11":"Rock Slide","12":"Aqua Tail","Type":"Rock","13":"Water","Power":"75","14":"90","15":"Ice Beam","16":"Ice","17":"90","18":"Dark Pulse ","19":"Dark","20":"80","21":"Rock Slide","22":"Rock","23":"75"}]
```

Ultimately, what I want is a Javascript array with the values indexed numerically like ["9", "9", "Blastoise"]

Comment: What is in your PHP array? It must be something like `array("9", "9", "Rock Slide", "Blastoise", "Water");`.

Comment: That last loop, what did it output? Actually, what is the output of `var_dump($jsPoke1);`? `$jsPoke1` is not an actual array, otherwise it wouldn't be outputted like that. It is converted to a string earlier in your script. We'll need that code to help you.

Comment: I just added some information, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is unclear weather you want just Blastoise or all the pokemon in `PlayerPokemon1` but I'll try and give an answer that would work either way. [You can try this code here](http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com?code=%24jsPoke1%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%5B%2F%2FBlastoise%0A%20%20%20%20'Number'%20%3D%3E%209%2C%0A%20%20%20%200%20%3D%3E%209%2C%0A%20%20%20%201%20%3D%3E%20'Blastoise'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'Name'%20%3D%3E%20'Rock%20Slike'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%2F%2FTotodile%0A%20%20%20%20'Number'%20%3D%3E%205%2C%0A%20%20%20%200%20%3D%3E%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%201%20%3D%3E%20'Totodile'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'Name'%20%3D%3E%20'Water%20Gun'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%5D%3B%0A%20%20%0A%24formattedPokemons%20%3D%20array_map(function(%24pokemon)%7B%0A%20%20return%20array_values(%24pokemon)%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%24jsPoke1)%3B%0A%0Aecho%20%22var%20PlayerPokemon1%20%3D%20%22.json_encode(%24formattedPokemons)%3B).

If your `$jsPoke1` array looks like

```
$jsPoke1 = [
  [//Blastoise
    'Number' => 9,
    0 => 9,
    1 => 'Blastoise',
    'Name' => 'Rock Slike',
    ],
  [//Totodile
    'Number' => 5,
    0 => 2,
    1 => 'Totodile',
    'Name' => 'Water Gun',
    ]
  ];
```

You can do

```
$formattedPokemons = array_map(function($pokemon){
  return array_values($pokemon);
}, $jsPoke1);
```

And then either do the following if you want all the pokemon in `PlayerPokemon1`

```
echo "var PlayerPokemon1 = ".json_encode($formattedPokemons);
```

Or this other thing if you just want Blastoise

```
echo "var PlayerPokemon1 = ".json_encode($formattedPokemons[0]);
```

Comment: I'm getting a <br /> in the script tag when I run the second line of code you gave me

Comment: Weird, are you using wordpress? [You may be interested in this link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87834/using-the-echo-command-adds-unwanted-br-tags-to-source)